# d3 filter duplicates names from csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

with `d3.csv` I am reading a csv that is then stored such that 
`console.log(data[0])` returns 
`Object {username: "mark", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0`}

Now I want to extract from `data` only the first occurence of each username. 
In python pandas I would have used `data.drop_duplicates(columns='username')`

EDIT: 
Consider the following example:

```
  var X =  [{username: "a", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
    {username: "b", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
    {username: "a", y: 1, x: 0, value: 0}
    {username: "c", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0}
    {username: "b", y: 1, x: 0, value: 0}]
```

it should return only:

```
  var Y =   [{username: "a", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
    {username: "b", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
    {username: "c", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0}
```

i.e. `f(X) = Y`

Comment: Do you want to filter duplicates or to find the first occurrence of each username? They are different things.

Comment: The first occurrence of each username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to find the first occurrence of each username, this question has nothing to do with D3, and can be solved with plain JavaScript.

There are several ways for doing this. A simple one is using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the value of the **first** element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. (emphasis mine)

Here is a demo. First, we get the unique values for usernames as an array:

```
var users = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.username
}))];
```

Then, we use a `map` with `filter` to get the first occurences:

```
var firstOccurrence = users.map(function(d) {
    return data.find(function(e) {
        return e.username === d
    })
});
```

Check the demo:

```js
var data = [{
  username: "a",
  y: 0,
  x: 0,
  value: 0
}, {
  username: "b",
  y: 0,
  x: 0,
  value: 0
}, {
  username: "a",
  y: 1,
  x: 0,
  value: 0
}, {
  username: "c",
  y: 0,
  x: 0,
  value: 0
}, {
  username: "b",
  y: 1,
  x: 0,
  value: 0
}];

var users = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.username
}))]

var firstOccurrence = users.map(function(d) {
  return data.find(function(e) {
    return e.username === d
  })
});

console.log(firstOccurrence)
```

Comment: thanks but I am not sure this is what I want. I need the first occurrence of each usename. not only mark.

Comment: In that case, please rewrite your question with a better wording.

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: @Donbeo I edited the answer, see if that's what you want. PS: `find` doesn't work on IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to keep track of what usernames have already been processed. Using the `username` as the key ensures the uniqueness of this value. To get the first occurence of this value instead of the last one, you further have to use [`Map.prototype.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) to check if each particular value has already been added.

```js
var X =  [
  {username: "a", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "b", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "a", y: 1, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "c", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "b", y: 1, x: 0, value: 0}
];
 
var uniqX = new Map();   // Construct map of unique usernames
X.forEach(x => { 
  if (!uniqX.has(x.username)) uniqX.set(x.username, x);  // Only add, if not present
});

var Y = uniqX.values();  // Retrieve the result set

console.log(...Y);
```

Or, rewritten for the sake of mathematical aesthetics:

```js
var X = [
  {username: "a", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "b", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "a", y: 1, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "c", y: 0, x: 0, value: 0},
  {username: "b", y: 1, x: 0, value: 0}
];

function f(_) {
  let uniqX = new Set();
  return _.filter(({username}) => !uniqX.has(username) && uniqX.add(username));  
}

var Y = f(X); 

console.log(...Y);
```